# How can I make sure my AWS application has access to some (network) path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed a .NET Core 2.0 application to AWS elastic beanstalk so now I have something like this:

http://someNameInventedByMe.elasticbeantalk.com/swagger

to test. One of the web api methods requires file path as input parameters. On my local machine, I can just give C:@Testdata.xml as argument (the '@' is string replaced by '/' inside my controller method). This works fine. Can my application running in AWS also get access to some network file path?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking.  "Network file path" on what network?  Note: *"One of the web api methods requires file path as input parameters"* sounds like an extremely dangerous design decision.  External requests should essentially never be able to specify fully-qualified paths, and any paths used need to be normalized/sanitized (not something you should try to write yourself) to prevent unintended access.

Comment: It should be an accessible file path, the same way I tested it on my local device. In production, the service (which is a microservice) will only be accessible by own microservices. Real users have no influence on the actual path to be used.